# Highlight a specific line series data point in multiple line series of Live Charts WPF

Tags: livecharts

I have been using Live Charts for a WPF application. I have a chart with multiple line series. The tooltip shows the data for all the line series. But on mouse hover on the chart, I would like to see the label of specific line series highlighted (in the tooltip). Is this possible?

Say, I have 10 line series in a chart. When I hover the mouse over any of the ten line series, the tooltip shows the same data. Is there a way that when I hover my mouse over 3rd line series, the data related to the 3rd line series must be highlighted somehow. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: related to https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/issues/532

Comment: Greate!! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: could you please add a simple example with two line series